# Your project has set `android.useAndroidX=true` but configuration `debugRuntimeClasspath` still contains legacy support libraries

Tags: java, android-studio, error-handling, compiler-errors, android-manifest

I am getting an warning in android studio when I run my app. the warning is-
***Your project has set `android.useAndroidX=true`, but configuration `debugRuntimeClasspath` still contains legacy support libraries, which may cause runtime issues.***
And a error-
***Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs***
I checked my manifest file and there is no error in my manifest file. I tried debugging the app but it still doesn't fix. I am getting this after updating android studio from android studio arctic fox to android studio bumble bee which is recently released. I updated the gradle version tried cleaning project, invalidating caches but nothing worked. I increased the memory heap size and enabled multidex but still it is not fixed. Please help me out.

Comment: Please review your project dependencies if they contain legacy libraries

Answer (score 29):

1. Comment this line in settings.gradle

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

2. Add this in build.gradle (project level):

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
```

3. Add in gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: still not working  have any other solution??

Comment: For me, It worked with the line "android.enableJetifier=true" and by setting maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in settings.gradle file.

Comment: jcenter() is shot down since February 1, 2022 and can no longer be used.

Comment: Why do we need `Jitpack.io` here?

Comment: I did same things without using `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` and it solved my problem

Answer (score 21):

Add these in gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Sync your `gradle` and Run the app. It worked fine for me and I didn't have to do the changes in `setting.gradle` and `build.gradle` (Project level) or any other files.

Comment: This worked fine and No needed to change anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is simialar to @JJ Smith one. But I didn't do anything to `build.gradle` file. So:

1. Comment this line in `setting.gradle`:

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

2. Make sure you have these 2 lines in `gradle.properties` (if not add them or change them to true):

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

3. Sync gradle

I **DID NOT** change the `build.gradle`(at project level) file. I report it here just for the sake of completeness:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        //...
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

If you have it, just remove it.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Damien

Comment the line

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

and add

```
android.enableJetifier=true 
android.useAndroidX=true
```